# SDK file name changed error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

So for another application I had to change the name of my whole developer file which contains eclipse, android sdk, and libraries. I changed where my libraries point to and such and all the errors are gone from my project but now when I debug (run) my app I get the following errors:

```
06-27 12:24:20.971: E/Trace(27090): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-27 12:24:20.971: D/ActivityThread(27090): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
06-27 12:24:20.971: D/ActivityThread(27090): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
06-27 12:24:20.971: D/ActivityThread(27090): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
06-27 12:24:21.051: W/dalvikvm(27090): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;)
06-27 12:24:21.051: W/dalvikvm(27090): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;)
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker;)
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): VFY: returning Ljava/lang/Object; (cl=0x0), declared [Ljava/lang/Object; (cl=0x0)
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x11 at 0x0002
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): VFY:  rejected Lcom/hasta/ezsite/MainActivity;.access$6 (Lcom/hasta/ezsite/MainActivity;)[Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker;
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): Verifier rejected class Lcom/hasta/ezsite/MainActivity;
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/hasta/ezsite/MainActivity;)
06-27 12:24:21.061: D/AndroidRuntime(27090): Shutting down VM
06-27 12:24:21.061: W/dalvikvm(27090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ce6438)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090): java.lang.VerifyError: com/hasta/ezsite/MainActivity
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1231)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-27 12:24:21.091: E/AndroidRuntime(27090):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 12:24:23.053: I/Process(27090): Sending signal. PID: 27090 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Under project properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> check Android Private Libraries. Presto.